# SwiftUI: remove view at animation end?

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
enum AnimationDirection {
    case opening
    case closing
}

struct AnimtionStateMod: AnimatableModifier {
    
    var progress: CGFloat = 0
    private(set) var direction:AnimationDirection = .opening
    
    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { progress }
        set {
            direction = progress > newValue ? .opening : .closing
            progress = newValue
            print("progress: \(progress). direction: \(direction)")
        }
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.opacity(1)
    }
    
}



struct PersonDetails: View {
    @State var person:Person
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            Color.yellow
            
            HStack {
                Text("PERSON")
                Spacer()
            }
            
            Text(person.name)
            
            Spacer()
            
        }
        .border(.red)
    }
}


struct Person: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}





struct ContentView: View {

    @State var persons = [Person(name: "A"), Person(name: "B"), Person(name: "C")]
    
    @Namespace private var gridSpace
    @State var selectedPerson:Person?
    @State var expandingPersonDetails:Bool = false
    var matchDetailsToPerson: Bool { !expandingPersonDetails }
    @State var matchSelectionToGridItem = true
    
    let c = GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 200, maximum: 400), spacing: 20)

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [c]) {
                    ForEach(persons) { person in
                        
                        ZStack {
                            Color.blue
                            Text(person.name)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            print(person.name)
                            withAnimation {
                                selectedPerson = person
                            }
                            
                        }
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: person.id, in: gridSpace, isSource: true)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            .zIndex(1)
            
            
            if let person = selectedPerson {
                
                PersonDetails(person: person)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: matchDetailsToPerson ? person.id : UUID() , in: gridSpace, isSource: false)
                    .frame(width: 600, height: 600)
                    .zIndex(2)
                    .onAppear {
                        withAnimation {
                            expandingPersonDetails = true
                        }
                    }
                    .onDisappear {
                        expandingPersonDetails = false
                    }
                    .transition(.identity)
                    .modifier(AnimtionStateMod(progress: expandingPersonDetails ? 1 : 0))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation {
//                            selectedPerson = nil
                            expandingPersonDetails = false
                        }
                    }   
            }   
        }
    }
```

It behaves like this:

[image]

What I am stuck on:

I want `PersonDetails` to be removed once it has finished animating back on the grid item. The open animation (from grid to expanded `PersonDetails`) looks like I want it to look. The close animation (when `PersonDetails` scales back to the related grid item) looks like I want it to look. But, I want `PersonDetails` to be removed once it lands back on the grid item.

I thought I could use `AnimatableModifier` to track the animation when going back on the grid item and then trigger `selectedPerson` to nil. I think I could use that approach, but, I am not sure if that is what I should be doing in this case.

How should I go about this?

JUST TO ADD FEEDBACK:

using `asperi`'s answer I get a different result. I am also using a newer version of Xcode, that's the only thing I can think of right now, but I wanted to provide feedback here for context:

[image]

Comment: I have feeling that something is redundant here, but I cannot understand what did you try to achieve... or what all that code is doing here... something like that :)

Comment: I can see where you're coming from. I just want the `PersonDetails` to animate back to the grid item it came from, and THEN be removed from the view. If I just set the `selectedPerson` to nil, it'll just go away without animating back...

Comment: AnimatableModifier is the only modifier make that things happen, but it needs lots of correct codes and the way you should apply it is important or simply use a delay animation and transitions which I thing that would be lighter and cleaner than AnimatableModifier.

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly imagined your needs (I'm still not sure), the effect can be achieved in simpler way - by animating just selected person and having person view with overlayed matching the same to keep origin in place.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

with slow debug animation for better visibility

[image: demo2]

Here is main part (updated with iPadOS fixed):

```
        ForEach(persons) { person in
            ZStack {
                if nil != selectedPerson {
                    PersonView(person: person)
                } else {
                    PersonView(person: person)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: person.id, in: gridSpace)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if nil == selectedPerson {
                                selectedPerson = person
                            }
                        }}

            }
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
    }
}
VStack {   // << to remove fluently
    if let person = selectedPerson {
        PersonDetails(person: person)
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: person.id, in: gridSpace)
            .transition(.scale(scale: 1))
            .frame(width: 360, height: 360)
            .onTapGesture {
                selectedPerson = nil
            }
    }
}
.animation(.default, value: selectedPerson)
```

[Complete test module is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestMatchedPersonDetailsFromGrid.swift)

Comment: Thanks. interesting. So, the "close" animation here switches back to the "blue" view before scaling back to the grid item instead of taking the expanded "yellow" view back to the grid item. I want to keep the closing animation like the one in the question where it shrinks back to the grid item and then removes its self once scaled down to match the grid item... (fadeout would be nice). So, just like shown in the question, but once landed on the item, it needs to be removed. May I ask why you're using the overlay? thanks.

Comment: hey, I just realized, that when I run this code on my end, it looks different (as I described it) than what posted here. I'll double check, but, I just pasted your code in Xcode to test it out. I am running Version 13.4 (13F17a). iPad Pro 12.9 iOS 15.5.

Comment: ok, so this code, on close animation, immediately switches to the "blue" state and THEN it scales down to the grid item.

Comment: I'll update and check, maybe Apple has "changed the rules" (ie. broken things), again. :) . Btw, matchedGeometryEffect replaces one view with another, so if we want to keep same in the initial place then we need to have another one same there (that's why I asked about expectations).

Comment: Interesting, updated & retested with Xcode 13.4 / 15.5, what you provided in update becomes iPad OS only effect... hmm

Comment: Updated with iOS/iPadOS both work

Comment: mmm, weird. I did not try the phone. I'll do more testing and see. thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Asperi's code is quite simple and effective. If you want a different approach, although a little more complicated, you can try setting a duration to the animation and - only after that - set the `selectedPerson` to `nil`.

First, inside `ContentView` set a constant for the duration of the effect:

```
    // This is the duration of the animation
    let effectDuration = 0.5
```

Then, use a transition with an animation based on the `expandingPersonDetails`  variable. You can completely drop the `AnimatableModifier`. Before dismissing the person detail, first change the variable `expandingPersonDetails` to place the view back to its original position. Only after the animation is over, using `.asyncAfter()` you can dismiss the `selectedPerson`. Here:

```
PersonDetails(person: person)

    // Use simple transition
    .transition(.opacity)

    // The duration must match the .asyncAfter method below
    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: effectDuration), value: expandingPersonDetails)

    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: expandingPersonDetails ? UUID() : person.id , in: gridSpace, isSource: false)
    .frame(width: 600, height: 600)
    .zIndex(2)
    .onAppear {
        withAnimation {
            expandingPersonDetails = true
        }
    }
    .onTapGesture {
        withAnimation {
            
            // Change this variable first
            expandingPersonDetails = false
            
            // When the animation is over, un-select the person
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + effectDuration) {
                selectedPerson = nil
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, I think `asperi`'s code is great. Just trying to figure out why it's rending differently on my end. Also, if I understand what is going on with the overlay play in his answer, it seems that each grid item draws the PersonView twice? Then the overlay stays in place during animation...

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer. There are so many people trying to make the problem a lot more complex than it really needs to be.